# Pandas Pivot Table Count Values (Exclude "NaN")

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

Given the following data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Site':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                   'x':[1,1,0,1,np.nan,0],
                   'y':[1,np.nan,0,1,1,0]
                   })

df

    Site    y   x
0   a      1.0  1
1   a      NaN  1
2   a      0.0  0
3   b      1.0  1
4   b      1.0  NaN
5   b      0.0  0
```

I'd like to pivot this data frame to get the count of values (excluding "NaN") for each column.

I tried what I found in other posts, but nothing seems to work (maybe there was a change in pandas 0.18)?

Desired result:

```
    Item  count 
Site            
a   y     2     
b   y     3     
a   x     3     
b   x     2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need pivot? `df.count()` will give you the count (excluding nans)?

Comment: Because I need a pivot table for another function (to calculate the percent of rows per column that contain 1).

Comment: Can you show how the resulting pivot table would look like?

Comment: Sure; I've updated the post.

Comment: I think it is complaining about the string when the functions are passed in a list. You can try `pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, index = "Site", values = ["x", "y"], aggfunc = [np.sum, lambda x: len(x.dropna())]).stack().reset_index(level = 1)`  instead.

Comment: I'm going to post it as a separate question because it's a bit more involved, it seems.

Comment: Sure, it's up to you.

Comment: Actually, I guess it isn't. Thanks for your help, @ayhan. This has turned a day long Excel ordeal into less than a second of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, index = "Site", values = ["x", "y"], aggfunc = "count").stack().reset_index(level = 1)
pvt.columns = ["Item", "count"]

pvt
Out[38]: 
     Item  count
Site            
a       x      3
a       y      2
b       x      2
b       y      3
```

You can add `pvt.sort_values("Item", ascending = False)` if you want y's to appear first.